# Alternate definitions of width (of a partial order) without Choice?

Tags: definition, order-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Say an *antichain* of a poset $P$ is a set of pairwise incomparable elements of $P.$ Typically, the *width* of a partial order is defined to be the supremum of the cardinalities of antichains of $P.$ When Choice fails, however, it seems as if this definition may be invalid (or perhaps simply unsatisfactory).

For example, if Choice fails, then there are two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ with incomparable cardinalities. Let $P=A\cup B,$ and given $a,b\in P,$ say $a\leq b$ iff $a\in A$ and $b\in B.$ Then $\leq$ makes $P$ a poset, and $A$ and $B$ are precisely the maximal antichains of $P$.

However, do the cardinalities necessarily form a lattice if Choice fails? If not, then it seems there need not be a supremum of $\bigl\{|A|,|B|\bigr\},$ so that this definition need not apply to this $P,$ and we need another one. If so, then what *is* the supremum of $\bigl\{|A|,|B|\bigr\}$? Clearly, $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ is an upper bound, but must it be the least? If so, why? If not, then what could it be?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for the cardinalities to form a lattice.

Comment: That's pretty much what I figured. In that case, how (if at all) might we define width if Choice fails?

Comment: No idea. There might not even be maximal antichains. It might be that every antichain is finite, but there are uncountable sets which are countable unions of finite sets. So what does it even mean to have a supremum...

Comment: Without choice, you can define an antichain to be a totally ordered set of incomparable elements of $P$, and take the supremum of the corresponding ordinals. But in any case it's unclear to me what the use of infinite widths is.

Comment: (I actually touched a bit on the topic when I wrote my masters thesis, although not in any way significant. I did recognize that when leaving the notion of finite width, one can run into a bog of troubles.)

Comment: @Qiaochu: There's only so much that ordinals can measure in the absence of choice. And sometimes it's not sufficiently useful.

Comment: Right. I'm not claiming this definition is useful in any way.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What "corresponding ordinals"? By "totally ordered" did you mean "well ordered"?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant well-ordered.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the cardinalities do not need to form a lattice without the axiom of choice.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are infinite Dedekind-finite sets of incomparable cardinality, and suppose $A, B$ both embed via $f, g$ into $C$, with $C=ran(f)\cup ran(g)$. Then it's easy to see that $C$ is also Dedekind-finite, so if we remove an element from $C$ we get a set of strictly smaller cardinality. On the other hand, since $A$ and $B$ are incomparable, we must have $X:=ran(f)\setminus ran(g)$ and $Y:=ran(g)\setminus ran(f)$ each nonempty, so both $A$ and $B$ embed into $C$ minus one element.

This shows that not only do such $A$ and $B$ not have a supremum, but given *any* set into which they both embed, there is a *strictly smaller* set into which they both embed.

---

Answering a question in the comments: there can indeed be posets with no maximal antichains. We can have a poset which is the disjoint union of $\omega$-many pieces $A_i$ which are each ordered as $\mathbb{Z}$, and elements of different pieces are incomparable, but so that the family $\{A_i: i\in\omega\}$ does not admit a choice function.